# Loop with conditions in python

Tags: coding-style, python, idioms

Consider the following code in C:

```
for(int i=0; i<10 && some_condition; ++i){
    do_something();
}
```

I would like to write something similar in Python. The best version I can think of is:

```
i = 0
while some_condition and i<10:
    do_something()
    i+=1
```

Frankly, I don't like `while` loops that imitate `for` loops. This is due to the risk of forgetting to increment the counter variable. Another option, that addressess this risk is:

```
for i in range(10):
    if not some_condition: break
    do_something()
```

**Important clarifications**

1. `some_condition` is not meant to be calculated during the loop, but rather to specify whether to start the loop in the first place
2. I'm referring to Python2.6

Which style is preferred? Is there a better idiom to do this?

Comment: I think this is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Which version of Python?

Comment: I think Python ought to have a construct like `do <expr> times:`, to allow you to make it explicit that you won't actually be using the loop counter.

Comment: Karl: `for _ in range(10)` seems to be a common way to denote this, but of course this is a horrible idea if you happen to be using gettext.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, the "`range` + `break`" style is preferred - but in Python 2.x, use `xrange` instead of `range` for iteration (this creates the values on-demand instead of actually making a list of numbers).

But it always depends. What's special about the number 10 in this context? What exactly is `some_condition`? Etc.

Response to update:

It sounds as though `some_condition` is a "loop invariant", i.e. will not change during the loop. In that case, we should just test it first:

```
if some_condition:
  for i in xrange(10):
    do_something()
```

Comment: 10 and range are just examples this could have been `for i in my_array`. As clarified in the question, `some_condition` controls whether the program needs to perform the loop or skip it at all

Comment: Your version is straightforward and works. I just wanted to spare additional indentation.  Thank you

Answer (score 10):

This might not be related, but there's what I'm used to do... If `some_condition` is simple enough, put it in a function and `filter` items you iterate over:

```
def some_condition(element):
    return True#False

for i in filter(some_condition, xrange(10)):
    pass
```

You can use this approach also when you iterate over some list of elements.

```
selected = filter(some_condition, to_process)
for i, item in enumerate(selected):
    pass
```

Again, this might not be your case, you should choose method of filtering items depending on your problem.

Comment: Or, making it even shorter and less readable: `for i in filter(lambda x: True, range(10)): do_something()`

Answer (score 4):

`for` loops with a constant upper bound are a bit rare in Python. If you are iterating over `somearray`, you might do:

```
for i in xrange(len(somearray)):
    if not some_condition:
        break
    do_sth_with(i, somearray[i])
```

or, better:

```
for i, item in enumerate(somearray):
    if not some_condition:
        break
    do_sth_with(i, item)
```